# Apply CSS rule to all elements inside?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some elements that goes like this

```
<div class="t-widget t-window">

Your code goes here

</div>
```

For that element and all elements i want to apply this rule

```
-webkit-box-sizing : content-box;
       -moz-box-sizing : content-box;
            box-sizing : content-box;
```

How easy that can be done?

Comment: all selector: `*{...}` ?

Comment: I dont want to all only to elements inside that element

Comment: Use your association powers... `.t-widget *{...}`? Wasn't that hard, was it? http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Comment: FYI there is no `-o-box-sizing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the below CSS setting:

**CSS:**

```
.t-widget, .t-widget ~ * { /* The ~ * selects all elements following it */
    color: red; /* Added just for illustration */
    -webkit-box-sizing : content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing : content-box;
    -o-box-sizing : content-box;
    box-sizing : content-box;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>Your code goes here</div> <!-- Style will not be applied to this -->
<div class="t-widget t-window">Your code goes here</div> <!-- Style will be applied from this point on -->
<div>Your code goes here</div>
<div>Your code goes here</div>
<div>Your code goes here</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AcCN4/1/)

**Edit:** Just now saw your comment that you want for child elements. For that use the below CSS.

```
.t-widget, .t-widget * {
    color: red;
    -webkit-box-sizing : content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing : content-box;
    -o-box-sizing : content-box;
    box-sizing : content-box;
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AcCN4/3/)

Here you can have a look at the [comprehensive list of CSS3 Selectors](http://w3.org/TR/selectors#selectors).

Comment: "Apply CSS rule to all elements inside" -> I guess it should be `.t-widget *`.

Comment: @Christoph: Sorry mate, I just read the *after* in question at first (it has now been edited). Only from the comments did I realize it was meant to be for child elements. Updated now :)

Comment: well, the principle stays the same +1 ☺